# Symfony2 dont show 500 error while throwing exception

Tags: symfony

Look at this simple code:

```
  public function test(){
    if(sth){ //true
      throw new Exception("Bla Bla");
    }
  }
```

And function in controller:

```
  try {
    test();
  } catch (Exception $e) {
    $toSend = $e->getMessage();
    return $this->render('view.html.twig', array('toSend' => $toSend);
  }
```

I want that function in controller render `view.twig.html` and send 'Bla Bla' in `toSend` variable.

While I'm getting `500 Internal Server Error - Exception`

Best Regards

Answer (score 4):

I see there is some syntax error in your code.

1. You have to write `throw new \Exception("Bla Bla")` instead of `throw Exception("Bla Bla")`
2. You have to write `catch (\Exception $e)` instead of `catch (Exception $e)`

If you dont put "\" before Exception class, it means that it will find Exception class in your current namespace. If it can't find it, it will throw exception.